# Navigation from one view to another view in IOS (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in IOS. I am confused in navigation.I have looked 3,4 methods to navigate from one view to another view controller. 
First

```
DashboardViewController *dashboard = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dashboard animated:YES];
```

Second :- Using push segue on clicking button.

Third :- I'm not clear for it, That is array of view controller. In which we get the view controller and then navigate.

Fourth:-

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle:nil];
        UserDashboardViewController *users =
        [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserDashboardViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:users
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
```

I am confused which is best way for navigation, and most important how to navigate using array of view controllers. Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what kind of views you use and how many views you have to manage. If your views are .xib files you will mostly use the first way, push segue on clicking you will use mostly if you use storyboards for managing your views

Comment: I am creating app of more than 10 view controller. I studied that first method increase the memory so its not good to use. Third method is good but don't know how to use. I am using story board not xib. I am only using xib for subview.

Comment: Depends. Nothing is best between those 4. Your 4th example is of `Present` not `Push`,

Comment: I am not sure with the memory issue but i can't believe that it increase the memory usage dramatically because you anyway have a stack of navigation controller that holds all your navigation controller.

Comment: I was using first method thats works very well but i stuck in logout condition. I clicked on logout button and use "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"login"];" and then "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];" but it not work properly.Then i used fourth method that work properly but in that case first method don't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way in my point of view.
[image]

Comment: Is this method is different from first?

Comment: Can you tell me one thing when i am clicking logout button,I firstly remove NsUser item then using  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Its not working properly. Don't why it is not working.

Comment: Please check this view controller is in the stack or not.